# How to webscrape with Selenium when URL remains static after click

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to Selenium/Firefox.  My goal is to go to my URL, fill in basic input, select a few items, let browser change the content and download a PDF from there.  Ideally, I would love to do it repeatedly later by looping a number of new items. As a first step, I manage to get the browser to work and change content once.  But I am stuck in getting the content out as find_elements_by_tag_name() seem to get me something funny rather than some usual HTML tag like what Beautifulsoup .find_all() would do.   Appreciate very much any help here.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


url ='http://www.hkexnews.hk/listedco/listconews/advancedsearch/search_active_main.aspx'

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path = 'C:\Program Files\Mozilla 
Firefox\geckodriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

StockElem = browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_txt_stock_code')
StockElem.send_keys('00772')
StockElem.click()

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_sel_tier_1'))
select.select_by_value('3')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_sel_tier_2'))
select.select_by_value('153')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_d'))
select.select_by_value('01')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_m'))
select.select_by_value('01')

select = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('ctl00_sel_DateOfReleaseFrom_y'))
select.select_by_value('2000')

#  select the search button
browser.execute_script("document.forms[0].submit()")

element = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

print(element)
```

Comment: Why are you using JavaScript to submit the form instead of using Selenium?

Comment: Good one and it's my knowledge gap here as I thought the site runs on some Javascript and that's the way to do it.  Alternatively, what would be the better method in Selenium to use to get the same result?   Thanks.

Comment: There are several ways, you can call either `.click()` or `.submit()` on a webelement. For example you can use: `browser.find_element_by_tag_name('form').submit()` or `find_element_by_tag_name('button').click()`. Click has to be on the button, submit can be on any element inside the form. Of course it's better to use an id, class or name for this because there can be more forms and buttons on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clicking on the Search button -- you have 5 links to download PDF files.

1. You should find those links by CSS selector: `.news`.
2. Then go through the list of links by index and click on each link to Download:

   `elements[0].click()` -- by clicking on the first link.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this:   element = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".news") but still couldn't get a list with 5 elements.

Comment: I got something like this:
 [<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="50b21b0f-34b7-4307-b0e6-11c229403c06", element="5958b9f6-0238-40bc-8781-5db1ee4585dd")>]  . When i tried to get_attributes['href'],  element.get_attribute('href')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-cf35332c1055>", line 1, in <module>
    element.get_attribute('href')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: @sunytest, I checked on FireBug -- and I see 5 links. You have only 1 element after `elements = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".news")`?

Comment: Correct.  I simply checked length. len(element)
Out[6]: 1

Comment: @sunytest, I updated the answer. The following code is correct: `elements[0].get_attribute("href")` -- if you have only 1 link.

Comment: element = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".news")
print(element)
print(element.get_attribute['href'])  is all that i tried

Comment: @sunytest, try what I wrote.

Comment: @ Ratmir:  thanks for the help.  I tried elements[0].get_attribute("href").   I get this instead. TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable  .  When you run the code, do you actually manage to capture 5 items?  I don't think my element object has anything on it at all.

Comment: @sunytest, I did the same (all your search parameters) -- and got 5 links after clicking on the "Search" button.

Comment: you are right.  It supposes to have 5 links.  But somehow my browser.find_element_by_css_selector didn't seem to get me anything.  I was hoping it would result 5 things and I could loop through it to find the one with name called "Global Offering" to download.  Anyway, the only way I could do is by "brute Force" to find out the exact "id" of this "Global Offering" and get the doc out directly.  If somehow, the site changes the "id", it won't work again.

Comment: @sunytest, I must use `find_elements_by_css_selector`-method if you have several elements. If I answer your question -- check a tick around my answer. Thanks.